# Where da lazers at?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I visited the site on my iPhone this morning and found it... Depressingly barren.

Where did my lasers go? Is this a new mobile stylesheet? Because it feels like the worst of both worlds - all the small targets and poorly optimized page width of the main site, none of the awesome lasers, charm, or soul.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could close as duplicate of MSO :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, we are starting with some basic designs to test mobile rendering.

The /minimal style is the "hello world" of mobile designs, it is the absolute minimal CSS and images necessary to render the site.

We will be improving this over the next few months.

Comment: Can we get a cookie to turn this off if we so choose? As of now, the site exists in a no-mans land where it offers none of the ease of use of a true mobile site, and none of the polish and great looks of the full design.

Comment: @Less If you haven't yet, [upvote this Meta request for exactly that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/view-standard-site-option-for-mobile-devices).

Comment: @less not entirely; the empty-cache perf of this site is about 300k whereas the empty-cache perf of /minimal is ~30k

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a new stylesheet for mobile devices. It's optimized purely for bandwith.

Comment: It's pretty terrible. :(

Comment: Aww, I loved seeing the full site on my iPhone. I have to agree this doesn't look as good.

Answer (score 1):

The low-fi skin has been made by [Moshe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142875/moshe) on [request on Jeff](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=532732#532732) when people complained about how some sites were... too styled. This low bandwidth CSS is now served to mobiles (iPhone, Android, others?) because the sprites are served in 16 color gifs.